# Getting Error on Checkout Page. Magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout

my store works good but sometime when I click on the *Checkout* button then it moves me to 
`http://xyz/checkout/noroutes` and them I came back to my homepage but when I click on other *checkout* button which is in the minicart then checkout page collapse and shows like
[image]

what is the issue n how can I sort this??

Comment: httml code is written where ?phtml  file or html file?

Comment: in the PHTML file Sir
`app/design/frontend/Ecomwares/wokiee/Ecomwares_Wokiee/templates/html/header.phtml`

Answer (score 1):

As you have using phtml and  want to get checkout page, then below code

```
location.href='<?= $block->escapeJs($block->getUrl("checkout"));?>'
```

**Instead of**

> location.href='https:/'+'/'+location.hostname+'/checkout/#shipping'

Comment: But Sir I'm still confused... the checkout page which is collapsed with step one n step 2 is this is the reason or that error might come from somewhere else